# How can I enable approved Instagram posting features with "instagram_basic" & "instagram_content_publish" permissions in my app's production env.?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-basic, instagram-content-publish

I've obtained approval for the `instagram_basic` and `instagram_content_publish` permissions through App Review for my app, which is meant to allow Instagram posting via the Facebook Graph API. During development, I successfully tested the feature using test credentials. However, even after 24 hours from the approval, the feature isn't working in the production environment. Can anyone in the community provide insights or suggestions to help me get this feature working for live users? Your prompt assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, it is working but testers are the worst. We have tried 3 month then today, finally, we got approved. And we are uploading same video and description about 1 month. You have to show every button every click. And told them what this is and what you can do with long description. If you are lucky, you get approved. You can create test account via facebook developer page and use that account. This is the one of our solution couple of reasons they not approve our app.